# Unable to correctly parse JSON object to a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

I have the following [Json data](https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-category-dataset) that I am trying to transform to a Javascript object. Initially I tried using `JSON.parse` but it was saying an error so I figured the Json object was incorrectly configured. I did the following to resolve the issue.

The JSON is given in the following form:

```js
{}{}{}...
```

But I wanted to change it to the following format:

```
[{},{},{}...]
```

So I did the following

```js
var news = fs.readFileSync("data.json", "utf8")

//Stringified data
var newsdata = JSON.stringify(news)

// add comma in between 
data = newsdata.replace('}{', '},{')


// The resulting data doesn't have a comma between individual objects
parsedNews = JSON.parse(data)
```

The `str.replace()` command isn't changing it to a desired format. How should I resolve the issue?

Comment: You still need to wrap it in `[]`

Comment: that is not the issue, the replace command isn't adding comma's

Comment: You need to use a regex to do a global replace e.g. `data = newsdata.replace(/}\s*\{/g, '},{')`

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't actually be calling `JSON.stringify`.